# Why is my CSV larger than my JSON file with identical data?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, bigdata

I used pandas to export a large dataset (510,000 rows) to CSV and JSON for comparison. Both files contain the same dataset.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ******  staff  187584246 Jun 24 16:23 case_06-24-16_16-14.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 ******  staff   14026640 Jun 24 16:24 case_06-24-16_16-14.csv.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 ******  staff  159802082 Jun 24 16:23 case_06-24-16_16-14.json
-rw-r--r--   1 ******  staff   13985789 Jun 24 16:23 case_06-24-16_16-14.json.zip
```

How is it possible that my CSV is larger than my JSON file?

Comment: cat few first lines of both csv and json

Comment: show us some section of the of files and we might be able to determine why

Comment: one idea that comes to mind is how they handle numbers? In JSON there is no distinction between integers and floating point numbers, so it's fine to just represent the float 2.0 as 2, whereas the csv might store the 2.0 so you can infer the type. Not sure if that's enough to explain the difference without seeing the data.

Comment: wouldn't a csv have fieldnames in row 0, as headers only?  while a json would repeat fieldnames for every single row?  also, the size discrepancy doesn't appear that way in your own list:  187584246 (csv) > 159802082 (json).

Comment: The title says CSV is larger while the question states otherwise?

Comment: I misspelled the question in the description. @AlvaroJoao corrected me. I will edit the description with a cat of both files when I have a chance.

Comment: Please add some snippet of the data. In csv and json

Answer (score 1):

Would be more easy if you showed some csv and json rows. My guess is that the characters used to separate the values are different in the two files and that's why you see a difference in file size.

The only thing is about this answer is that I would then expect the json to be bigger.

```
A;B;C
1;2;3
4;5;6
```

2x3 = 6 characters used to separate the values

```
A:[1,4],
B:[2,5],
C:[3,6]
```

5x2 + 4 = 14 characters used to separate the values

That's why it would be more easy if we had some idea about the structure of the files.

Answer (score -2):

**JSON** it's a human-readable file. It's not optimized.

In few words **JSON** file will use **more characters** and elements to represent the same data as in **csv**.

**Csv** idea is optimized to move data.

> E.G:
>
> `A;B;C`
>      `1;2;3`
>      `4;5;6`
>      `2x3 = 6 characters used to separate the values`
>
> `A:[1,4],`
>      `B:[2,5],`
>      `C:[3,6]`
>      `5x2 + 4 = 14 characters used to separate the values`

Comment: Which would make sense if the question didn't ask why the CSV file is larger. The title seems to correlate with the data given, the last sentence of the question doesn't^^

Comment: @KilianKoeltzsch hey you are right probably he misspelled the header of the question. Thanks for notice that.

Comment: Actually you are right. My explanation does not make sense. @KilianKoeltzsch

Comment: I misspelled the question in the description. Thanks for correcting me!